# How can I remove a subfolder in an IIS rule?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I've recently moved a site from: www.mycompany.com/subfolder1 to www.mycoproduct.com.  The url structure is the same between the site except for "subfolder1" in the new site.  I'm trying to write a rule to remove the subfolder but I'm not having any luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

pattern:

```
^subfolder1/(.*)
```

rewrite action:

```
{R:1}
```

or

```
http://www.mycoproduct.com/{R:1}
```